# Cllocation doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

Pop up asking for location doesn't show up or when it shows up it disapears after few seconds, location works only when going through settings and setting allow location services on always. Im thinking this might be a problem with the actual pop up window.

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let authStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus = 
CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    if authStatus == .notDetermined {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    if authStatus == .denied || authStatus == .restricted {
        showLocationServicesDeniedAlert()
        return
```

Comment: You need to make sure that it's being called from the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

The locationManager may not be a local variable for this code to work properly. The instance of CLLocationManager you create gets deleted right after the authorization prompt shows up. After deleting the locationManager instance iOS dismisses the location authorization prompt.

Make sure it's a member variable of your view controller or app delegate class.